# How to include questionnaire data with behavioral counts in lmer() maximal logistic regression model?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I’m using a maximal logistic regression model to analyze some data. I would like to keep using this technique if possible, just include more data in the model. The main data I’m looking at is counts of a particular behavior over items in a sequence, and I would like my analysis to also include data from a post-experiment questionnaire (8 items, 1-9 Likert scored). Here’s some info about my data:

```
'data.frame':
Pair          : Factor w/ 36 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
SpeakerID     : Factor w/ 72 levels "10A","10B","11A",..: 21 22 21 22 22 21 22 21 21 22 ...
Speaker       : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 ...
Condition1     : Factor w/ 4 levels "ANTI","CONTROL",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "contrasts")= num [1:4, 1:3] -0.333 1 -0.333 -0.333 0.25 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. .. : chr  "ANTI" "CONTROL" "IN" "OUT"
.. .. .. : NULL
Condition2         : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","90","180": 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 ...
..- attr(*, "contrasts")= num [1:3, 1:2] 0 -0.5 0.5 -0.5 0.25 0.25
.. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. ..$ : chr  "0" "90" "180"
    .. .. ..$ : NULL
Item         : Factor w/ 16 levels "MAP1","MAP10",..: 1 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 2 ...
Foo       : num  0.847 1.099 1.946 -1.099 -0.452 ...
wtsFoo          : num  0.952 0.889 2.286 0.889 0.468 ...
Close      : num  -1.798 0.202 -1.798 0.202 0.202 ...
Similar    : num  0.505 0.505 0.505 0.505 0.505 ...
Like       : num  -0.833 0.167 -0.833 0.167 0.167 ...
Task1Hard   : num  -0.89 4.11 -0.89 4.11 4.11 ...
Task2Hard: num  -1.02 2.98 -1.02 2.98 2.98 ...
```

My analysis is based on this guide to empirical logit analyses:
http://talklab.psy.gla.ac.uk/tvw/elogit-wt.html
So far, so good. In my regression model, I’m testing the fixed effects of Condition1 (4 levels) and Condition2 (3 levels) on Foo (the behavior, expressed as a proportion converted into empirical logit form, see link for how and why). Pair, Pair:Subject (Subject nested within Pair) and Item are included as random effects. Condition1 is between-subjects/pairs and Condition2 is within-subjects. Here’s the model I’m using in R:

```
model <- lmer(Foo ~ Condition1*Condition2 + (1+Condition1 | Pair) 
+ (1+Condition1 | Pair:Subject) + (1+Condition2 | Item), weights=1/wtsFoo, data)
```

This all works fine, but here’s where it gets fun. Where should the questionnaire data go?

Bad idea #1: Each participant has one score for each questionnaire item, so each questionnaire item type should be included as a fixed effect, so that Foo can be predicted by any of the variables discovered in the post-experiment questionnaire (things like social closeness and task difficulty). This is a terrible idea because the questionnaire items are NOT independent variables from Condition1 and Condition2, and if I include them as fixed effects it will introduce a mess of multicollinearity and will just be flat-out wrong.

Bad idea #2: Analyzing the questionnaire data separately. Not such a bad idea, just one that my committee doesn’t like.

Less bad ideas: please suggest a model that allows me to observe the effects of Condition1 and Condition2 on questionnaire items (Close, Similar, Like, Task1Hard, Task2Hard) AND allows me to observe the effects of questionnaire items on Foo. Failing that, explain to me why the only good thing to do is analyze the questionnaire separately from the observation data.

I've read around on Stackexchange and I haven't seen this particular problem covered, although some answers come close to looking useful, I don't yet have the R or stats chops to make them work for me. If I've missed something obvious, please clue me.